# JQuery compare large datasets

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, csv, memory-management

I have call to my database that returns an object containing valid values

Object
1.   ErrorDetails:Object

2. ExistingInspections:Array[36640]
3. ValidAttNamesandLengths:Array[3]
4. ValidDownValues:Array[11]
5. ValidRatingTypes:Array[52]
6. ValidStaffAndDepts:Array[431]

I also have a datatable generated from a csv. 
I need to validate the values in the csv against the values returned in that validation object but i'm not sure what the most efficient way to do this? I could use two for loops and loop through each object in the validation model against each cell but i could have up to 1500 rows with 15 columns and using the for loops is pretty much the slowest way i could think of

Comment: Not an answer, but a few loop optimization tips-- cache the length (instead of calculating on each pass), and avoid `while` and `forEach`, as they tend to be quite a bit slower.  At least that's what I remember for JSPerf...

Answer (score 0):

You may use objects and associative arrays.

With Objects you can see the value as obj['field'], so it should be already efficient.

With arrays you can transform them to associative arrays once and then access them in constant time each time reading the values in your csv (maybe with some transforming function).

For sure is much quicker than looping over those structures for each value in the csv.

Making examples is quite difficult as I don't know how your arrays and/or objs are made, neither their contents..

Comment: sorry so here is an example of the csv transform(1 row) and one of the validation model
Example CSV
Array[1]
1.   0:Object
1.   Asset Info Notes:null
2.   AssetGroup:"Parks"
19. Work Order Required? (Y/N):"N"
Validation Model
 
1.   Object
3.   ValidAttNamesandLengths:Array[3]
1.   0:Object
1.   AttributeLength:250
2.   AttributeName:"DetailsOfAssetInfoChanges"
3.   __proto__:Object
2.   1:Object
3.   2:Object
4.   length:3
5.   __proto__:Array[0]
4.   ValidDownValues:Array[11]
5.   ValidRatingTypes:Array[52]
6.   ValidStaffAndDepts:Array[431]